# Split php and html into separate files

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am studying an example of filling out a form.

https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/basic-form-validation-with-php/blob/main/index.php

And I can't figure out how to properly separate HTML and PHP code if I need to get the output of incorrectly filled fields on the same page.

I want to get something like that:

**index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Fruit Survey</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>The World of Fruit</h1>
<h2>Fruit Survey</h2>
<form class="wrapper" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text"
           name="name"
           id="name"
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($values['name']);?>">

    <?php if (in_array('name', $errors)): ?>
      <span class="error">Missing</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

  <label for="address">Address</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text"
           name="address"
           id="address"
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($values['address']);?>">

    <?php if (in_array('address', $errors)): ?>
      <span class="error">Missing</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text"
           name="email"
           id="email"
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($values['email']);?>">

    <?php if (in_array('email', $errors)): ?>
      <span class="error">Missing</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="field-label">How many pieces of fruit do you eat per day?</div>
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio"
             name="howMany"
             <?php if (isset($values['howMany']) && $values['howMany'] == "zero") echo "checked"; ?>
             value="zero">
      0
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio"
             name="howMany"
             <?php if (isset($values['howMany']) && $values['howMany'] == "one") echo "checked"; ?>
             value="one">
      1
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio"
             name="howMany"
             <?php if (isset($values['howMany']) && $values['howMany'] == "two") echo "checked"; ?>
             value="two">
      2
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio"
             name="howMany"
             <?php if (isset($values['howMany']) && $values['howMany'] == "twoplus") echo "checked"; ?>
            value="twoplus">
      More than 2
    </label>

    <?php if (in_array('howMany', $errors)): ?>
      <span class="error">Missing</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

  <label for="favoriteFruit">My favourite fruit</label>
  <div>
    <select name="favoriteFruit[]" id="favoriteFruit" size="4" multiple="">
      <?php
      $options = ["apple", "banana", "plum", "pomegranate", "strawberry", "watermelon"];
      foreach ($options as $option) {
        printf(
          '<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>',
          $option,
          (in_array($option, $values['favoriteFruit'])) ? "selected" : '',
          ucfirst($option)
        );
      }
      ?>
    </select>
    <?php if (in_array('favoriteFruit', $errors)): ?>
      <span class="error">Missing</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

  <label for="brochure">Would you like a brochure?</label>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"
           name="brochure"
           id="brochure"
           <?php if (isset($values['brochure']) && $values['brochure'] == "Yes") echo "checked"; ?>
           value="Yes">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```html
<?php
$errors = [];
$fields = ['name', 'address', 'email', 'howMany', 'favoriteFruit', 'brochure'];
$optionalFields = ['brochure'];
$values = [];
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (empty($_POST[$field]) && !in_array($field, $optionalFields)) {
      $errors[] = $field;
    } else {
      $values[$field] = $_POST[$field];
    }
  }

  if (empty($errors)) {
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
      if ($field === "favoriteFruit") {
        printf("%s: %s<br />", $field, var_export($_POST[$field], TRUE));
      } else {
        printf("%s: %s<br />", $field, $_POST[$field]);
      }
    }
    exit;
  }
}

//MYSQL
    require_once('db-connect.php');
    
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users_data (name, address, email, howMany, favoriteFruit, brochure) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); 
    
    $statement->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $address, $email,  $howMany, $favoriteFruit, $brochure); 
    
    if($statement->execute()){
    print "Hello, " . $name . "!, your request has been sent!";
    }else{
    print $mysqli->error; 
    }
?>
```

But for that I need to replace `<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` with `<form method="post" action="process.php">`
But then field validation and error output in the form does not work.

Comment: `process.php` is not used in your form submission process as far as I can see. Also, rather than using `PHP_SELF` as the form action you can omit the action completely - there is a potential vulnerability with PHP_SELF

Comment: I prefer to have PHP in control, using `echo` to build bits of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

like this man

php:

```
    <?php
$errors = [];
$fields = ['name', 'address', 'email', 'howMany', 'favoriteFruit', 'brochure'];
$optionalFields = ['brochure'];
$values = [];
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (empty($_POST[$field]) && !in_array($field, $optionalFields)) {
            $errors[] = $field;
        } else {
            $values[$field] = $_POST[$field];
        }
    }
```

And what ever you put as a value in html forms

like this

```
<label for="favoriteFruit">My favorite fruit</label>
<div>
  <select name="favoriteFruit[]" id="favoriteFruit" size="4" multiple="">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="plum">Plum</option>
    <option value="pomegranate">Pomegranate</option>
    <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
    <option value="watermelon">Watermelon</option>
  </select>
</div>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="howMany" value="zero"> 0
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="howMany" value="one"> 1
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="howMany" value="two"> 2
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="howMany" value="twoplus"> More than 2
</label>

<label for="name">Name</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
  </div>

<label for="address">Address</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="">
  </div>

<label for="email">Email</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
  </div>
```